# Rails: Profile method execution count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling

I am looking to implement a profiling bar in our local Rails development environment. This will be a horizontal bar located at the top of every page (only in our development env).

The bar should contain the following (at the least):
- Memory allocation
- Number of times a specific method gets fired (we have some heavy methods we would like to keep an eye on). **This is the most important stat.**

There are some profilers out there (rails-prof) but, what is a good approach to implementing such features? Would rails-prof be able to count method execution?

Comment: have you looked into [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)

Comment: Yes I have, I haven't seen a way to count the number of times a method gets fired during a request.

Comment: Also look into [ActiveSupport::Instrumentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html). You might want to store the number of method call somewhere (db, redis, memcached, plain file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) is what you need. You need to watch this [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler) for a good explanation. Or you can ask the [community](http://community.miniprofiler.com/) more specific questions.

Comment: Rack mini profiler is the way to go. Gives very good stats, easy to use and shows the number of times each route gets fired which works for us.